# How to find out the execution sequences in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

Haskell is able to run the two function calls one after the other on case 1 but confused on case 2 below, why?

```
ghci> id id 1   -- case 1

ghci> (+1) id 1 -- case 2
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what would you expect the output to be in the second case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Function application is left-associative, which means your examples are parsed as:

```
(id id) 1
((+1) id) 1
```

The former reduces thus:

```
(id id) 1
id 1
1
```

The latter doesn't typecheck. `(+1)` has a type of `Num n => n -> n`, whereas `id` has a type of `a -> a` which is not a number.

If you meant `(+1) (id 1)`, you have to write it out with parentheses.

Comment: It's perhaps even clearer why the second expression doesn't work if you write it as `(id + 1) 1`.

Comment: Thanks. The point is that `(id id)` passes typecheck because `id` is typeless, isn't is? Are there any other typeless functions existing in Haskell?

Comment: @sof `id` isn't typeless. Everything has a type. `id`'s type is `a -> a`. In the expression `id id` the first `id` is being used at `(a -> a) -> (a -> a)`

Comment: Sure, everything has a type. I actually mean `id` takes a pure generic parameter. I'd like to know about any other pure generic functions I'm unaware of.

Comment: Other pure generic functions I could come up with might look like `f :: a -> b -> a` etc, but they seem useless.

Comment: @sof I don't think there are other interesting examples of "pure generic"/maximally polymorphic functions beyond the ones you mention -- after all, you can't do much in an implementation if you don't know anything about the types. The `a -> b -> a` one, by the way, is called `const`, and surprisingly enough it can be quite helpful -- it is very commonly used as a way to pass a fixed value to something that expects a function.